# Calculate width of each bar of Barcode in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, barcode

I have a barcode and I would like process it in matlab and calculate the width of each bar in a 1-D barcode in pixels.

I have tried converting the image to gray scale through graythresh level and converted it to binary as well.

```
%read the image code3
barz=imread('barcode1.jpg');
grayBarz=rgb2gray(barz);

binImage = imbinarize(barz,graythresh(barz));

s = regionprops(binImage == 0,'Area','PixelIdxList');
imshow(barz);
```

I want the width in pixels of each bar in the barcode.

[image: Barcode Image]

Comment: Please upload `barcode1.jpg` image to your question.

Comment: Uploaded the image for your reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime it is fun to be able to do things without needing the full *image processing toolbox*.

The solution below allows you to count the pixel width of every black bar, without needing any additional toolbox:

```
%% Read the image
barz=imread('barcode.jpg');
grayBarz=rgb2gray(barz);

%% Extract an horizontal line in the middle
sz = size(grayBarz) ;
idxMidLine = round(sz(1)/2) ; % index of a line roughly in the middle
eline = grayBarz(idxMidLine,:) ;    % extract a line
eline(eline<128) = 0 ;              % sharpen transitions
eline = ~logical(eline) ;           % convert to logical (0=white / 1=black)

%% Now count the pixels
npts = numel(eline) ;   % number of points in the line

% Find every transition:
    % high to low   => -1
    % no change     =>  0
    % low to high   => +1
idd = find( diff(eline) ) ;

% this contain the start and end indices of every interval
ddd = [ 1 , idd ; ...
        idd , npts ] ;

% This contains the width of every bar (white and black),
% in order from left to right
barWidth = diff(ddd) ;

if ~eline(1)
    % The first interval is 0 (is white)
    pixBarWhite = barWidth( 1:2:end ) ;
    pixBarBlack = barWidth( 2:2:end ) ;
else
    % The first interval is 1 (is black)
    pixBarBlack = barWidth( 1:2:end ) ;
    pixBarWhite = barWidth( 2:2:end ) ;
end

nBarWhite = numel(pixBarWhite) ;
nBarBlack = numel(pixBarBlack) ;

%% Display results
fprintf('Found a total of %d black pixels along the horizontal,\n',sum(pixBarBlack))
fprintf('spread over %d black bars,\n',nBarBlack)
fprintf('Individual bar pixel thickness:\n')
for k=1:nBarBlack
    fprintf('Bar %02d : Thickness: %02d pixels\n',k,pixBarBlack(k))
end
```

For your image it will return:

```
Found a total of 599 black pixels along the horizontal,
spread over 49 black bars,
Individual bar pixel thinchness:,
Bar 01 : Thickness: 13 pixels
Bar 02 : Thickness: 07 pixels
Bar 03 : Thickness: 20 pixels
% [edited to keep it short]
Bar 47 : Thickness: 20 pixels
Bar 48 : Thickness: 07 pixels
Bar 49 : Thickness: 13 pixels
```

Note that the variable `pixBarWhite` also contain the pixel thickness of all the white intervals between the black bars. It might come handy for later ...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you alread have the regionprops of the bars the width can be easily obtained through

```
'MinFeretProperties'
```

or

```
'MinorAxisLength'
```

If your bars are paralell to the image raster you can also use the smaller dimension of the `'BoundingBox'`

https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For fun, here's an implementation using Python OpenCV

- Convert image to grayscale and Otsu's threshold
- Detect all vertical lines and draw onto mask
- Find contours on mask and sort from left-to-right
- Iterate through contours and find pixel width of each line

---

**Results**

> Barcode Width: [13, 7, 20, 27, 7, 19, 12, 13, 13, 7, 6, 13, 20, 7, 14, 7, 6, 12, 20, 7, 13, 27, 19, 7, 6, 6, 13, 7, 27, 7, 14, 19, 6, 19, 6, 13, 13, 7, 5, 6, 26, 6, 6, 13, 6, 12, 20, 7, 13]
>
> Barcode Bars:  49
>
> Total Pixels:  599

**Code**

```
import cv2
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np

# Load in image, grayscale, and Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Detect vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,80))        
remove_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel)
cnts = cv2.findContours(remove_vertical, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cv2.fillPoly(mask, cnts, (255,255,255))

# Find contours on mask and sort from left to right
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts, _ = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right")

# Iterate through contours and find width of each line
barcode_width = []
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    current = image.copy()
    cv2.rectangle(current, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), -1)
    cv2.putText(current, 'Width: {}'.format(w), (15,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.5, (36,255,12), 3)
    barcode_width.append(w)
    cv2.imshow('current', current)
    cv2.waitKey(175)

print("Barcode Width:", barcode_width)
print('Barcode Bars: ', len(barcode_width))
print('Total Pixels: ', sum(barcode_width))
cv2.waitKey()
```